# How can use you leverage Change Feed in Cosmos DB to insert/update in one container based on the insert/update performed in another container?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Suppose there is a document in CustomerContainer which contains details of a customer, such as the following

```
    { 
       "customerId":"929607CC-454F-44A3-B77A-9893044EC2A",
       "entityType":"Customer",
       "customerCode":"1234",
       "email":"abd@gmail.com",
       "firstName":"Tripty",
       "lastName":"Chauhan",
       "phoneNumber":"935465664",
       "address1":"Tithal Road",
       "address2":"Valsad",
       "zipcode":"3567",
       "createdDate":"2019-09-15T23:14:25.7251173Z"
    }
```

There is another VehicleCollection which contains a vehicle document,

```
    { 
       "vehicleId":"9CAB9D21-BF41-42D3-90B3-910C0B607429",
       "entityType":"Vehicle",
       "VIN":"FDFGH89GFDGFD09193209",
       "partialVIN":"193209",
       "vehicleDetailId":"38CBEAF7-5858-4EED-8978-E220D2BA745E",
       "make":{ "Id":"B57ADAAD-C16E-44F9-A05B-AAB3BF7068B9","make":"BMW"},
          "model":{ 
             "Id":"2F4D4D7F-2B10-48D6-A432-3DEA445D64E5",
             "model":"ABDS"
          },
          "trim":{ 
             "Id":"2AC50FE4-4B1C-4034-AD29-51028B96FF6F",
             "trim":"5.6L/ASMD"
          },
          "year":{ 
             "Id":"81B5859D-F953-44C5-BB86-D41FE11086B3",
             "year":2008
          },
       "createdDate":"2019-09-15T23:14:25.7251173Z"
       }
```

VehicleConatiner also contains a document that maps Vehicle and Customer.

I want to perform insert operation in CustomerVehicle document, whenever a new vehicle document is added in VehicleContainer and update operation when an existing customer document is modified.

```
    { 
       "customerVehicleId":" 5F214745-B400-4D8E-9F97-D1FEBFDD079E",
       "entityType":"VehicleCustomer",
       "vehicleId":"9CAB9D21-BF41-42D3-90B3-910C0B607429",
       "customerId":" 929607CC-454F-44A3-B77A-9893044EC2A",
       "VIN":" FDFGH89GFDGFD09193209",
       "firstName":"Tripty",
       "lastName":"Chauhan",
       "customerType":1,
       "email":"tripty@gmail.com",
       "phoneNumber":"978576575",
       "createdDate":"2019-09-15T23:14:25.7251173Z"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Change Feed does not distinguish between Inserts and Updates, so you'd need to have some field in the VehicleCollection that you can leverage to tell one scenario from another. It could be adding a `createdTime` as an epoch that you can compare.

To consume the [Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#features-of-change-feed), you can either:

- Create and host your application using the [Change Feed Processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor). Since this is already part of the client SDK, you have all the tools you need to query and save as you need.
- Leverage Azure Function's [Cosmos DB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions) to create an Azure Function that will wake up and start whenever there are changes. To save changes in another collection you can use the [Cosmos DB Output Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#output) to either just save documents or if you need to do a mix of querying and saving, you can [obtain the client instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#http-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-documentclient-c) and do the operations.

Regardless of the choice, in both cases you'd receive a list of changes and you'd have to apply some logic to identify which are inserts and which updates, and act accordingly.